# Efficiently selecting a subset from a bigger selection in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a monstrous query in Oracle SQL. My problem is that I need to take the % of two related queries.

So, what I'm doing is:

```
SELECT type*100/decode(total, 0, 1, total) as result
from (SELECT
(select count(*) from tb1, tb2, tb3
where tb1.fieldA = tb2.fieldB
and tb2.fieldC = tb3.fieldD
and tb3.fieldE = 'Some stuf') as type,
(select count(*) from tb1, tb2, tb3
where tb1.fieldA = tb2.fieldB
and tb2.fieldC = tb3.fieldD) as total from dual) auxTable;
```

As you can see my variable called type is a subset of the total variable. This is a simplified example of a much bigger problem..

Is there any efficient way of selecting the subset(type) from the total and then getting the percentage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a more efficient way of doing this:

```
SELECT type*100/DECODE(total, 0, 1, total) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(DECODE(tb3.fieldE, 'Some stuf', 1, 0)) AS type
      FROM tb1, tb2, tb3
     WHERE tb1.fieldA = tb2.fieldB
       AND tb2.fieldC = tb3.fieldD
);
```

This `SUM(DECODE(tb3.fieldE, 'Some stuf', 1, 0)` will get a count of all records for which `tb3.fieldE` = `'Some stuff'`. Alternately, you can use:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN tb3.fieldE = 'Some stuff' THEN 1 END) AS type
```

It that `CASE` will return `NULL` when `fieldE` is not the chosen value, and `NULL`s are not counted in `COUNT()`.

Comment: Thank you! I used the CASE option, it's so simple.. I love it!